# query optimization in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, query-optimization

I have the following two models

```
class Creative < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :creative_size
end

class CreativeSize < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :creatives
end
```

In an effort to minimize database hits, I'd like to perform one query which joins the two tables and gives me access to creatives and their sizes without needing to touch the database again. The following gets the job done:

>> query = Creative.all :joins => :creative_size
>> query[0].creative_size.common_name

However, I'd really like to have an instance method in Creative

```
def name_of_size
  self.creative_size.common_name
end
```

but when I do so, the following code makes two database queries:

>> query = Creative.all :joins => :creative_size
>> query[0].name_of_size

Is there any way to use Creative#name_of_size without hitting the db again? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this works or not but please, give a shot!

```
query = Creative.find(:all, :joins => :creative_size).name_of_size
```

Comment: Creative.find(:all, :joins => :creative_size) returns an Array and name_of_size isn't defined on Array, so this won't work. But thanks